# Algorithm to schedule interviews between two sets of people

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation, matching

I have two sets of people - **Set A** and **Set B**. Both sets are of the same size, say *n*.

People from **Set A** need to interview *m* people from **Set B** and vice-versa where *m < n*. You can imagine that it is a match-making session between the two sets.

For each person in **Set A** and **Set B**, they have been pre-matched with *m* people from the other set such that none of the pre-matches are **repeats**.

How to schedule *m* time slots such that

- Each of the *n* people from both sets interviews one of their pre-matched person from the other set in each time slot
- No-one has two interviews at the same time slot
- By the end of the *m* slots, each and everyone has completed all the interviews with their pre-matches

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hold it, you cannot guarantee only m time slots. Take n=2, m=1: If both A1 and A2 have been assigned to interview B1 AND both B1 and B2 have been assigned to interview A1 - then the 1st time slot will be very inefficient as A1 interviews B1 and A2 & B2 do nothing. Also need clarification on whether A1 having interviewed B1 covers B1 now having interviewed A1? Otherwise next slot goes to B1 interviewing A1, and the other guys *still* wait :-).

Comment: Definitely a good point. In my case, I am looking at *n>= 20* and *m <=5*. But yea, in the edge case you mentioned, *m* might not be enough. So the solution needs to include a way to check if m time slots are even feasible. *m* will be the minimum but in some cases, more than *m* slots might be required.

Comment: Btw, is this a real world case? Would be most interesting! :-)

Comment: @Stormwind Yep it is. Working on implementing an interview scheduling mechanism for Mentor Match-Making Platform based on a pre-filled Application Form.

Comment: Nice! Posted 1/2 answer, hope it brings some thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent the pre-matches as a graph, where the members of the two sets are represented as nodes and the matches as undirected edges. This will be a bipartite graph as no member of A is matched to another member of A (same for B).

Then, you want to find an edge-coloring of this graph with `m` colors. An edge-coloring assigns colors two every edge, such that no two edges sharing a common node have the same color. If we assume that the colors represent the time slots, this translates exactly to the requirement that every person can only have a single interview at any time.

There are a variety of algorithms for this problem. Take a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring#Optimally_coloring_special_classes_of_graphs) for some references.

Comment: I wonder if there is something missing from the question. What would the answer be if n=2 and m=1, and all persons are matched with the first person in the opposite set? Or maybe i misunderstand the word "repeats"?

Comment: As far as I understand, it is impossible for all persons from B to be matched to A1 (or A2) as A1 would then have two matches, violating m=1.

Comment: Maybe the Q was intended that way, but is imho badly phrased: "For **each person** in Set A and Set B, they have been pre-matched with m people from the other set". **Each person** is pretty much == **all persons** == n persons? Also, an "interview" is imho always directional - one asks, one answers. I haven't heard of people interviewing each other... Maybe "meeting" had been a better word.

Comment: Let me add a bit of clarification.

For every a1 in A, there exists *m* element subset B1 so that a1 meets only those members in B1 and vice versa.

Every member of A meets exactly *m* members of B and vice versa. By repeats, I meant that no member of A will meet a member from B more than once.

Probably the term interview is not appropriate as it imputes directionality. In a dating interview, for example, there is no directionality.
@NicoSchertler I have been looking at graph-coloring algorithms but yet to come up with a solution.

Comment: Thanks @NicoSchertler . I ended up using a modified version of BFS graph colouring.

Answer (score 0):

**To create the matches in the first place**

Put the data sets standing against each other and do straight connections between opposite slots. The first matching is 1:1. Then, for each remaining m, rotate B one step up (or down) and re-do the straight connections. Example with n=7 and m=1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 (one column of pairs is one interview time):

```
 │A B│  │A B│A B│  │A B│A B│A B│  │A B│A B│A B│A B│  │A B│A B│A B│A B│A B│  │A B│A B│A B│A B│A B│A B│ 
 ├───┤  ├───┼───┤  ├───┼───┼───┤  ├───┼───┼───┼───┤  ├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤  ├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤ 
 │1 1│  │1 1│1 2│  │1 1│1 2│1 3│  │1 1│1 2│1 3│1 4│  │1 1│1 2│1 3│1 4│1 5│  │1 1│1 2│1 3│1 4│1 5│1 6│ 
 │2 2│  │2 2│2 3│  │2 2│2 3│2 4│  │2 2│2 3│2 4│2 5│  │2 2│2 3│2 4│2 5│2 6│  │2 2│2 3│2 4│2 5│2 6│2 7│ 
 │3 3│  │3 3│3 4│  │3 3│3 4│3 5│  │3 3│3 4│3 5│3 6│  │3 3│3 4│3 5│3 6│3 7│  │3 3│3 4│3 5│3 6│3 7│3 1│ 
 │4 4│  │4 4│4 5│  │4 4│4 5│4 6│  │4 4│4 5│4 6│4 7│  │4 4│4 5│4 6│4 7│4 1│  │4 4│4 5│4 6│4 7│4 1│4 2│ 
 │5 5│  │5 5│5 6│  │5 5│5 6│5 7│  │5 5│5 6│5 7│5 1│  │5 5│5 6│5 7│5 1│5 2│  │5 5│5 6│5 7│5 1│5 2│5 3│ 
 │6 6│  │6 6│6 7│  │6 6│6 7│6 1│  │6 6│6 7│6 1│6 2│  │6 6│6 7│6 1│6 2│6 3│  │6 6│6 7│6 1│6 2│6 3│6 4│ 
 │7 7│  │7 7│7 1│  │7 7│7 1│7 2│  │7 7│7 1│7 2│7 3│  │7 7│7 1│7 2│7 3│7 4│  │7 7│7 1│7 2│7 3│7 4│7 5│
```

Unfortunately, the example above is the most simple and straightforward way. In addition to that, there are numerous other ways, resulting in a potentially huge amount of different pairings. If n,m is for example 7,3 one could rotate the B data set with not one but two positions per round. Or, one could have an extra offset in the pointer to B when halfway through A. Or, if n is bigger, one could (probably - becomes hairy) have that offset plus other-than-one steps for the second half of A in the B rotation. As long as B doesn't wrap around, almost anything is possible. The bigger n is in comparison to m, the more possibilities there are to scramble.

And, eventually, A and B need not be sorted numbers starting from 1. They can be just any numbers.

**Solving this problem**

As always, knowing the data helps. If one knows how the matches were originally created, it may be possible to do some shortcuts and conclusions based on that knowledge. If for example I knew that the matchings were created the above way, and I knew n and m, then I'd simply create the right table and do a search/slot-in of the given matches.

If not, one could use a [solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solver) or some of the openings mentioned in the Wikipedia article in Nico Schertlers answer. For my part, I'm usually to lazy to dig into such, so I like to try the bruteforce alternatives if the data seems not to explode too much.

Bruteforce would mean creating all possible combinations and then filtering those that meet the conditions.

Unfortunately, this makes a poor SO answer (been pending for two weeks in the browser), as i don't have the time to dig into the solution now. I'm sorry. Hopefully i can complete it later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I am adding some sample datasets. We are very close to a solution using a similar approach. Appreciate the help. Sample Prematch Map A10: [B8,B5,B7] A1: [B2,B3,B9] A3: [B1,B5,B9] A2: [B4,B6,B10] A5: [B1,B2,B6] A4: [B2,B3,B8] A7: [B6,B7,B9] A6: [B4,B5,B10] A9: [B7,B4,B10] A8: [B1,B3,B8] B2: [A1,A4,A5] B4: [A2,A6,A9] B5: [A3,A6,A10] B6: [A2,A5,A7] B7: [A7,A9,A10] B1: [A3,A5,A8] B10: [A2,A6,A9] B3: [A1,A4,A8] B8: [A4,A8,A10] B9: [A1,A3,A7] Typical size of A and B is 50 and number of pre-matches is 3. PS: Is Stormwind a WOW reference?